# Change path of url flask with regex

Tags: python, regex, flask

In flask I a `before_request` function which does some checks and returns the user to a different url if necessary.

I have something similar to the following example which where I get `request_url` I now want to change this from: `https://www.example.com:5000/user/profile/` to `https://www.example.com:5000/us/user/profile/`

```
@app.before_request
def check_location():
    country = request.cookies.get('country')
    if country != g.country:
        url = request.url
        url = re.sub('.com[^\/]*', '.com/us', url)
        return redirect(url, 301)
```

I tried some regex but this does not work when using dev server with a port. So my question is:

1. How do I write this regex a better way to get a better match.
2. Is it okay todo this with regex or does Flask have a better way?

Comment: Is this request coming from within your app or outside?...because if it's the former, why don't you add the language in the url at the first place, without going all the trouble using `re`.?

Comment: @IronFist  Outside. If the user is coming from US and clicked on a url from google that is in english store, I will need to redirect them? Maybe there is a better approach to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use groups:

```
url = "https://www.example.com:5000/user/profile/"
url = re.sub('.com[^\/]*', '\g<0>/us', url)
print url # https://www.example.com:5000/us/user/profile/
```

From the docs:

> In addition to character escapes and backreferences as described above, \g will use the substring matched by the group named name, as defined by the (?P...) syntax. \g uses the corresponding group number; \g<2> is therefore equivalent to \2, but isn’t ambiguous in a replacement such as \g<2>0. \20 would be interpreted as a reference to group 20, not a reference to group 2 followed by the literal character '0'. The backreference \g<0> substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Comment: Thanks, never knew about groups.